# Spring boot mvc legacy integration issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hi I am integrating spring boot with legacy application using spring boot legacy.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is the context listener i am using. After integration my controller endpoint is

HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

The same application when run standalone is giving response properly . What is the miss in integrating legacy.